# Not working register page can't find error

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets

I've created an almost full working login system, but my registration page doesn't work because nothing is written on db, cannot understand why... any ideas?

Here's the jsp login page "LoginPage.jsp":

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
 <table>
 <form action="RegistraUtenteServlet" method="get">
 <tr><td><b>Nome</b>
 <td><input type="text" name="nomeDaRegistrare"><td></tr>
 <tr><td><b>Cognome</b></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="cognomeDaRegistrare"></td></tr>
 <tr><td><b>Email</b></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="emailDaRegistrare"></td></tr>
 <tr><td><b>Username</b></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="passwordDaRegistrare"></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Registrati"></td></tr>
 </form>
 </table>
```

Here's the manager class "UtentiManager.java":

```
 public class UtentiManager {

public void registraUtente(String nomeDaRegistrare, String cognomeDaRegistrare,String emailDaRegistrare, int tipoDaRegistrare, String passwordDaRegistrare) throws SQLException {
    Connection con = DBConnectionPool.getConnection();
    String query = "INSERT INTO utenti(nome,cognome,email,tipo,password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, nomeDaRegistrare);
    ps.setString(2, cognomeDaRegistrare);
    ps.setString(3, emailDaRegistrare);
    ps.setInt(4, tipoDaRegistrare);
    ps.setString(5, passwordDaRegistrare);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    ps.close();
}
}
```

Here's the servlet "RegistraUtenteServlet.java":

```
 public class RegistraUtenteServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        UtentiManager um = new UtentiManager();
        String nomeDaRegistrare = request.getParameter("nomeDaRegistrare");
        String cognomeDaRegistrare = request.getParameter("cognomeDaRegistrare");
        String emailDaRegistrare = request.getParameter("emailDaRegistrare");
        String passwordDaRegistrare = request.getParameter("passwordDaRegistrare");
        int tipoDaRegistrare = 1;
        um.registraUtente(nomeDaRegistrare, cognomeDaRegistrare, emailDaRegistrare, tipoDaRegistrare, passwordDaRegistrare);
    }  finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/** 
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegistraUtenteServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

/** 
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegistraUtenteServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

/** 
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
 }
```

Please help!

Comment: What doesn't work? Any exception? What are the expected and actual behaviors?

Comment: Even if other components of the application like login and showUsers work, the INSERT doesn't work, nothing is inserted into db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `registraUtente` method never commits and close the connection. Change it to

```
public void registraUtente(String nomeDaRegistrare, String cognomeDaRegistrare,String emailDaRegistrare, int tipoDaRegistrare, String passwordDaRegistrare) throws SQLException {
    Connection con = DBConnectionPool.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        String query = "INSERT INTO utenti(nome,cognome,email,tipo,password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, nomeDaRegistrare);
        ps.setString(2, cognomeDaRegistrare);
        ps.setString(3, emailDaRegistrare);
        ps.setInt(4, tipoDaRegistrare);
        ps.setString(5, passwordDaRegistrare);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
    }
    finally {
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException ignored) {
            }
        }
        try {
            con.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Full working now...
I've a question if you want..
Why the same code without "commit" works in a simple javaapplication and doesn't work in a jsp/servlet page?

Comment: Because the simple Java application probably get its connection directly from the driver, which returns a connection with autocommit enabled. But autocommit should almost never be used. Your webapp probably uses a connection pool, which returns poolable connections with autocommit disabled (and that's a good thing).